# Expectation of a sequence of random variables based on a set of iid Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation, extreme-value

This is a rather convoluted problem: I'll my best trying to explain it. So, we have $m$ iid standard Gaussian RVs $Q_i$. We get a realization from each of them, and these values $q_1,\dots,q_m$ are now the means of $m$ sequences of independent Gaussian RVs, $\{X_{1n}\},\dots,\{X_{mn}\}$, with mean $q_i$ and $\sigma=1$.

I define a sequence $Y_n$ of random variables, which is a function of the $\{X_{1n}\},\dots,\{X_{mn}\}$ in the following way: for each $n$, $Y_n$ is equal to $\max_\limits{i}X_{in}$ with probability $\epsilon$, otherwise we choose one of the $\{X_{1n}\},\dots,\{X_{mn}\}$ at random. In other words:

$$\begin{equation}
  Y_n=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \max_\limits{1\leq i\leq m}X_{in}, & p=\epsilon \\
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
       X_{1n} &  \ p=\frac 1m \\
       .    & \\
       .    & \\
       X_{mn} & p=\frac 1m\\
       \end{array}\right. & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation} $$

I would like to compute:

1. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y_n|q_1,\dots,q_n]$$
2. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y_n]$$

Can you help me? The main issue for the first one is that the $\{X_{1n}\},\dots,\{X_{mn}\}$ are independent but not id (the means are different). For the second one, I have some sort of a sketch of a proof. Since I'm averaging over the variability of the $Q_i$, I can assume the $\{X_{1n}\},\dots,\{X_{mn}\}$ to be iid with mean $0$ and $\sigma=1$. I use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/473237/169160) to compute the expectation of the maximum of $m$ Gaussian random variables as

$$ E[\max_i X_i] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t \dfrac{d}{dt} \Phi(t)^m\ dt=c_m $$

Now, for each $n$, $Y_n$ is either equal to $Z_n=\max_i X_{in}$ with probability $\epsilon$, or it's chosen at random among Gaussian RVs with mean 0. Thus we can introduce two auxiliary random variables, a Bernoulli $B$ with $p(B=1)=\epsilon$, and a discrete uniform $\mathcal{U}\{1,m\}$. I would dare to write

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_n]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y_n|B]]=c_m\epsilon+(1-\epsilon)\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{in}|\mathcal{U}]=c_m\epsilon+(1-\epsilon)0=c_m\epsilon$$

Does this make sense? Can it be made rigorous? What about question 1?